# AEM 6.1 Touch UI Dialog - Is it possible to disable widget validation by selector?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, dialog, aem

I want to reuse pretty convenient listener which located by following path:

`libs/cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog/dropdownshowhide/clientlibs/dropdownshowhide/js/dropdownshowhide.js`

I regard case when I have several usages of `dropdownshowhide` listener on dialog (to show/hide different groups of widgets).

It allows me enable hidding/unhidding of other components based on the selection made in the dropdown/select.

In my case there are widgets which have required="{Boolean}true" properties. When I try submitting my dialog of course I can not do it as some fields are not valid.

My question is Can I disable validation by some selector?

Example of widget groups:

```
<fieldSet
   jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
   sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/fieldset"><!--widgets--></fieldSet>
    <!--or some container-->
<container
   jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
   sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container"><!--widgets--></container>
    <!--or some separated widget-->
<textfield
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield"/>
```

Ideally I would to it will not send data of such widgets. I mean to it disables widget inputs.

I do not want to manage hidden widgets and post them data.